# What are the suggested ide or plugins for cucumber.js?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, bdd

I'm having some difficulties on choosing tools related web development(mainly on top of node.js) driven by cucumber.js. Actually I'm newbie to cucumber and web development but in charge of introducing cucumber to my company. Although I have some experiences on SpecFlow on .Net development, this new world is not easy to me. :-(
I have many many questions but let me ask about choosing the ide or plugins just for now. What is the best or good ide for cucumber.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also more of a text editor person than an IDE aficionado. That being said, I've had the chance to see [Jetbrains Webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) being used on a Node.js project (involving Cucumber.js) and it seemed pretty good.

Also, [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is very popular these days.

Comment: Ok, the Webstorm looks great. I didn't try it yet, but [its cucumber support](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/cucumber.html) looks as good as the SpecFlow plugin on Visual Studio. Webstorm is great and Sublime Text looks also good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Cucumber.js, but I have used Cucumber and Lettuce (a Python clone of Cucumber), and I've always just used Vim with it. Works absolutely fine for me. If Vim isn't your cup of tea, both Emacs and Sublime Text have plugins for dealing with Cucumber feature files.

In all honesty I don't think IDE's are a good choice for Node.js, and not just because I'm firmly in the text editor camp of the IDE vs editor debate. Node is a relatively new platform and so IDE support will be lacking somewhat. Sublime Text is a wonderful text editor with a shallow learning curve, and it will do a perfectly good job.

Comment: I didn't know Sublime Text has cucumber plugins. I'll definitely try them. Thanks!